# Accessing GMail Imap Api via OAuth 2.0 and private key aka Service Account

Tags: gmail, google-api, oauth-2.0, gdata-api, gmail-imap

I am currently trying to use a Service Account and its P12 key to 
connect to the Imap server of a simple Gmail user.

I successfully implemented it for a domain wide delegation service 
account as described in 
http://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/wiki/GmailAndXOAUTH2 .

However I am having trouble connecting to a plain old gmail account.

The code to generate the OAuth 2.0 token is:

```
public static String getAccessToken(String email) throws Exception {
       HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();

JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SingleUserCredentials.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes("https://mail.google.com/")
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
    new java.io.File(SingleUserCredentials.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .setServiceAccountUser(SingleUserCredentials.EMAIL)
            .build();

    credential.refreshToken();
    return credential.getAccessToken();
}
```

I am then connecting to the ImapStore like:

```
String authToken = getAccessToken(SingleUserCredentials.EMAIL);

OAuth2Authenticator.initialize();

IMAPStore imapSslStore = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToImap(
    "imap.gmail.com",
    993,
    SingleUserCredentials.EMAIL,
    authToken,
    true);
```

I am always getting an Exception in thread "main" 
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Invalid credentials 
(Failure).

At least two things are strange here:

1. Imap with OAuth 2.0 private key works fine for domain wide delegation of a Google Apps domain.
2. The certificate I am using for the simple gmail account works perfectly fine for GDrive and other Google Services of that user.

Comment: Hi, are you able to credential.refreshToken()? I tried to implement it in C# but I can't even refreshToken(), google returns 400 bad request all the time.

Comment: I tried the java sample as well, but still getting 400 with "error : access_denied"

Comment: As I wrote above - it does not work for private accounts - at least for me...

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I'm trying it with domain accounts, still wouldn't work...